# Setting terms of specific powers in a sympy expression to zero

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have a sympy expression of the following form:

```
a, b = symbols('a b')
expr = a + a/b + a/b**2 + a**2/b**2 + a/b**3
```

I want to set any terms where the exponent of `b` is larger than the exponent of `a` to zero, such that the result is like this:

```
newexpr = a + a/b + a**2/b**2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you detail your assumptions a bit? Is your expression always a sum of terms? And is each term always a power of `a` divided by a power of `b` without other factors?

Comment: the terms are always powers of `a` divided by powers of `b`, but there are arbitrary factors multiplying each term. More specifically, I am interested in the limit of a quantity when `b` is very large, while `a` is proportional to `b`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by doing:

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c = sp.symbols('a b c')
expr = a + a/b + a/b**2 + a**2/b**2 + a/b**3
newexpr = sp.limit(expr.subs(a/b, c), b, sp.oo).subs(c, a/b)
newexpr
```

`out[1]: a + a/b + a**2/b**2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short plan for this:

- we make the substitution `1/b -> c`
- we rewrite the resulting expression as a multivariate polynomial in `a`,`c`
- we decompose the poly into monomials and only keep those terms that have `exp_a >= exp_c` , and we finish by substituting back `c -> 1/b`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from sympy import *
a, b = symbols('a b')
expr = a + a/b + a/b**2 + a**2/b**2 + a/b**3

def truncate(e):
    c = symbols('c')
    e1 = e.subs(S(1)/b,c)
    p = 0
    for m in poly(e1,a,c).monoms():
        exp_a,exp_c = m
        if exp_c <= exp_a:
            p += a**exp_a * (1/b)**exp_c
    return p

truncated_expr = truncate(expr)

print(truncated_expr)
```

OUTPUT:

```
a**2/b**2 + a + a/b
```